# Trigger a macro when selecting a blank cell in a specific column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a small DB in excel for that i need to **trigger a macro when selecting a blank cell in a specific column**. How to do that?

Comment: Please include the code. Is there a function to fire an event after a cell got focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can trigger it from Event `Worksheet_SelectionChange`

In my code, I activate a msgbox only if user selects **1 BLANK CELL** and from column C

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Column = 3 And Target = "" Then
    'do something
    MsgBox "I activate"
End If

End Sub
```

**It won't trigger if User selects more than 1 cell.**

Adap it to your needs.

> More info about
>   [Worksheet_SelectionChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-selectionchange-event-excel)

Comment: Might need compensating for multiple cells as target. Suppose someone decided to select all of column C?

Comment: @Jeeped Good point there! Let me update the answer

Comment: Thank you guys for your help :)